# Getting Random button

Tags: c#

I have button 1-2-3...12 and I want to randomly get 4 of them (not repeating) and then give them a single color, for example red.  How can I do that?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Button[] LeftArr = new Button[12] { button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12 };

        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= LeftArr.Length; i++)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Button ShipHere = rnd.Next( button1, button12 );

           // this is where i'm stuck
        }
```

Comment: Minor peeve, but once you want to get non-repeating 'random' numbers, they become non-random. Truly random numbers have a chance of repeating

Comment: i don't want to argue about numbers beeing random or not. i just need 4 different buttons from my list, got randomly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to make sure you don't keep creating a new `Random` object every iteration in the loop. Otherwise you will end up with duplicates.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

List<Button> randomButtons = new List<Button>(4);

for (int i = 0;i < 4;++i)
{
    Button chosenButton;

    // Keep looping until we get a button we haven't already picked
    do
    {
        chosenButton = LeftArr[rnd.Next(0, LeftArr.Length)];
    } while (randomButtons.Contains(chosenButton));

    randomButtons.Add(chosenButton);
}

foreach (Button button in randomButtons)
    button.BackColor = Color.Red;
```